# Как оптимально перестроить тело условия?

Tags: php, if, mysql

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильнее сделать условие типа такого?

```
$selll = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sellref WHERE idUser='$_GET[idRefere]'");
while ($sell = mysql_fetch_array($selll)) {

    if ($sell[0] == '0') { //Если в таблице пусто
                echo "Норм";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }

}
```

Comment: К вопросу не относится, но, все же, рекомендую погуглить "sql инъекции". У вас на эту тему в коде дыра размером с паравозное депо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```
$selll = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM sellref WHERE idUser='$_GET[idRefere]'");

if (mysql_num_rows($selll)) {    
    echo "Норм";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Не то. В результате всегда будет одна строка. Нужно проверять значение от `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @KiTE, а я что написал? присмотритесь - SELECT COUNT(*)

Comment: @mountpoint, вы проверяете mysql_num_rows. А это количество записей. Этот запрос в любом случае вернет одну запись.

Comment: @KiTE, нет. Эта функция может и ноль вернуть. Вы еще не проснулись видимо

Comment: @mountpoint, [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php) возвращает количество строк в результате sql-запроса.

`SELECT COUNT(*) ...` - это агрегатный запрос, и он, без группировки, всегда возвращает одну единственную строку.

Дальше продолжать?..

Comment: @KiTE, извиняюсь, понял свою ошибку

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = mysql_query(strtr(
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sellref WHERE idUser=":idUser"',
    [':idUser' => mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['idRefere'])]
));
if (mysql_result($r, 0, 0)) {
    echo 'Есть записи';
} else {
    echo 'Нет записей';
}
```